# Adding more joins to a select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I am having some trouble trying to add 2 more joins to a select. The bellow works for me:

```
FROM
    TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C ON A.REQUESTED_BY = C.USER_NAME
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 D ON A.COORDINATOR = D.USER_NAME
INNER JOIN TABLE4 E ON A.ID = E.PARENT_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE5 F ON E.ID = F.ID
```

But I need to get more information, so I tried something like this (added the last 2 rows):

```
FROM
    TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C ON A.REQUESTED_BY = C.USER_NAME
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 D ON A.COORDINATOR = D.USER_NAME
INNER JOIN TABLE4 E ON A.ID = E.PARENT_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE5 F ON E.ID = F.ID
INNER JOIN TABLE6 G ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 H ON G.COORDINATOR = H.USER_NAME
```

And this isn't working like it should.

Question: How can I add the last two joins to make the select works? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you joining Table G on A.ID = B.ID?   Don't you want some column from G in the join condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually joining to TABLE6 (G) anywhere. I would think that this join:

```
INNER JOIN TABLE6 G ON A.ID = B.ID
```

should be something like this instead:

```
INNER JOIN TABLE6 G ON A.ID = G.ID
```

And as a side note, I hope you're using table aliases that are more meaningful than A, B, C, etc. in your real code. ;-)

Comment: Given that this obviously isn't his real query, I'd be surprised if this is the answer.   And it's not exactly correct that he isn't joining to Table6.   He's effectively doing a cross join.